# OpenSCAD render is empty

Tags: stl, render, 3d-modelling, openscad

I’m in the process of designing a helix, and have done the blade in AutoCAD, to later on export it to .stl and finish the design in OpenSCAD.

The problem here is that when I try to render it (F6), the result is incomplete (only Joints.stl shows up). Although I have tried to fix both .stl files several times, the problem persists.

Thanks in advance

Edit: If it helps I made the .stl using AutoCAD and Blender.

(this is my code)

```
module pal() {

    translate([1.5,100,0.2])
        rotate([0,-10,0])   
import("Helix_Final.stl", convexity=100);

}
pal();
rotate([0,0,120])
    pal();
rotate([0,0,-120])
    pal();

translate([0,0,8.4])
import("Joints.stl");
```

[Helix_Final.stl](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1EpiPwwBbHvDU-XiVnH4-6qGgI6qFOPBP&export=download)
[Joints.stl](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1-MqW6KNoeSvJoWMKQ1P3MCsRnlzfRvlu&export=download)

It also gives the following log:

```
Saved backup file: C:/Users/eleme/Documents/OpenSCAD/backups/Joints¿-backup-
qHp13132.scad
Compiling design (CSG Tree generation)...
Rendering Polygon Mesh using CGAL...
ERROR: CGAL error in CGAL_Nef_polyhedron3(): CGAL ERROR: assertion violation! 
Expr: e->incident_sface() != SFace_const_handle() File: /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-
mingw32.static/include/CGAL/Nef_S2/SM_const_decorator.h Line: 326 
ERROR: CGAL error in CGAL_Nef_polyhedron3(): CGAL ERROR: assertion violation! 
Expr: e->incident_sface() != SFace_const_handle() File: /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-
mingw32.static/include/CGAL/Nef_S2/SM_const_decorator.h Line: 326 
ERROR: CGAL error in CGAL_Nef_polyhedron3(): CGAL ERROR: assertion violation! 
Expr: e->incident_sface() != SFace_const_handle() File: /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-                
mingw32.static/include/CGAL/Nef_S2/SM_const_decorator.h Line: 326 
Geometries in cache: 8
Geometry cache size in bytes: 11954368
CGAL Polyhedrons in cache: 1
CGAL cache size in bytes: 1378168
Total rendering time: 0 hours, 0 minutes, 11 seconds
   Top level object is a 3D object:
   Simple:        yes
   Vertices:      661
   Halfedges:    3182
   Edges:        1591
   Halffacets:   1864
   Facets:        932
   Volumes:         2
Rendering finished.
```

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with your Helix_Final.stl, have you try cleaning up the stl? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/FAQ#Why_is_my_imported_STL_file_only_showing_up_with_F5_but_not_F6

Comment: @CashLo Yes I did. Using all kind of tools, and it still doesn´t work.

Comment: I'll try again anyway, I have a good feeling about it this time.

Comment: Still didn't work. I clened it using MeshLab this time.

Comment: What should it look like? Maybe you could just create the object in openSCAD itself.

Comment: Not really, but that's the way to go most of the times.

Comment: It's a propeller

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the files are located in the same directory.